# Why we need flush in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I have recently started with hibernate 3.x and I am confused about the statement "**Flushing the session forces Hibernate to synchronize the in-memory state of the Session with the database**".

Please help me to understand the below points -

1. flush synchronize the in-memory state of the Session with the database What does it mean does it mean that query for example insert statement is executed and the data is saved into the table but we could not see the data in other session.
2. After flush where this data will be resides in session object or in database table itself.
3. How about the exception scenario occurs in case of any exception.

Please help me to understand the working of flush with an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forces the session to flush. It is used to synchronize session data with database.
When you call session.flush(), the statements are executed in database but it will not committed.

If you dont call session.flush() and if you call session.commit() , internally commit() method executes the statement and commits.

So **commit()= flush+commit**.

So seesion.flush() just executes the statements in database (but not commits) and statements are NOT IN MEMORY anymore. It just forces the session to flush.

Flush mainly used when you are dealing with thousands and millions of records.
So while dealing with such number of records we use batch update and flush.

```
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Employee emp = new Employee(.....);
    session.save(emp);
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

In above example if you do not call flush it may throw **OutOfMemoryError**.

You can check out this post about [flushing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)

Comment: Why can't we commit directly forget about the statement commit=flush+commit for some time. imagine flush is not at all there in picture then What would be the disadvantage if I commit directly.

Comment: Consider a scenario there are 10k insert statement in session and your memory size is very low. In this if you flush the records then insert statement will be executed on database but data will not be reflected on database as long as you did not commit the operation. Now you want to rollback those insert statements you can roll it back because we did not committed the operation.We generally convert 10k records into 10 groups of 1k records because we do not have huge memory to store these record in session

Comment: If we committed that operation then we can not roll it back.

Comment: So it means that after flush if I rollback the transaction and then commit the transaction .The data will not be saved in database.

Comment: @Monica after flush data will be cleared from memory

Comment: Yes. flush->rollback->commit data will not be saved in database

Comment: Are you sure after flush data will be clear from memory or else we have to explicitly call clear method ?

Comment: I'm sure data will be clear from memory means any hibernate statements which are in session will be executed on database side and session will get  cleared

Comment: Do you have any doubts?

Comment: Ok So if I will try to find the flushed  data in last statement in a same session from where it will find the data in database no as it's not committed yet , in session no as you said it's clear from there as well.So from where it will find the data.

Comment: If you just flushed the session then data will be available to you at database side after commit operation.

Comment: You can check out hibernate java-doc for commit and flush for more information.

Comment: yes you are right I have ran a small demo and it's working as you said.